# Strange conversion from NSUInteger to floats

Tags: math, nsuinteger

I have the following code:

```
NSUInteger one = 1;
CGPoint p = CGPointMake(-one, -one);
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(p));
```

Its output:

```
{4.29497e+09, 4.29497e+09}
```

On the other hand:

```
NSUInteger one = 1;
NSLog(@"%i", -one); // prints -1
```

I know there’s probably some kind of overflow going on, but why do the two cases differ and why doesn’t it work the way I want? Should I always remind myself of the particular numeric type of my variables and expressions even when doing trivial arithmetics?

P.S. Of course I could use `unsigned int` instead of `NSUInteger`, makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you apply the unary `-` to an unsigned value, the unsigned value is negated and then forced back into unsigned garb by having `Utype_MAX + 1` repeatedly added to that value. When you pass that to `CGPointMake()`, that (very large) unsigned value is then assigned to a `CGFloat`.

You don't see this in your `NSLog()` statement because you are logging it as a signed integer. Convert that back to a signed integer and you indeed get -1. Try using `NSLog("%u", -one)` and you'll find you're right back at `4294967295`.

`unsigned int` versus `NSUInteger` DOES make a difference: `unsigned int` is half the size of `NSUInteger` under an LP64 architecture (x86_64, ppc64) or when you compile with `NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64` defined. `NSUInteger` happens to always be pointer-sized (but use `uintptr_t` if you really need an integer that's the size of a pointer!); `unsigned` is not when you're using the LP64 model.

Answer (score 0):

OK without actually knowing, but reading around on the net about all of these datatypes, I'd say the issue was with the conversion from a NUSInteger (which resolves to either an int (x32)  or a long (x64)) to a CGFloat (which resolves to either a float(x32) or double(x64)).

In your second example that same conversion is not happening. The other thing that may be effecting it is that from my reading, NSUinteger is not designed contain negative numbers, only positive ones. So that is likely to be where things start to go wrong.